# Google App Engine database model

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need a simple application in GAE:

I have users:

```
public User {
    private @Id Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and messages

```
private Message {
    private @Id Long id;
    private Key sender;
    private Key reciever;
    private Date sendDate;
}
```

The problem is:
I need to fetch all messages sended and recieved by given user sorted by dandDate.

I think I choose wrong model.

Can you advice me anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE sender = 'givenUserID' OR reciever = 'givenUserID' ORDER BY 'sendDate'
```

Comment: If I not misstaken, it is not available to use "OR" in BigTable queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just change sender and receiver to be of String type and in testing make sure you execute your query (That will automatically set them as indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) ([pdf](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine)), a fascinating talk given at Google I/O by Brett Slatkin. He addresses the problem of building a scalable messaging services.